# Ошибка с пробелами и с return

Tags: python, return

```
def summa(message):
    global amount
    try:
        amount = int(message.text.strip())
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Непонял')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summa)
        return *Ошибка: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level*

   if amount > 0:
       markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
       btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/EUR', callback_data='usd/eur')
       btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('EUR/USD', callback_data='eur/usd')
       btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/GBP', callback_data='usd/gbp')
       btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Другое', callback_data='else')
       markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Валюта', reply_markup=markup)> Здесь выводить тоже самую ошибку: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level
   else:
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи число больше нуля')
       bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summa)
```

В консоль выводит:

```
   if amount > 1:
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Забавно, что в ошибке у вас другой код, чем в вопросе (другое сравнение)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ваши ошибки:

- В питоне строки обособляются с помощью кавычек, поэтому сделайте так:

```
return 'Ошибка: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level'
```

- Перед `if` и `else` у вас по 3 пробела, а надо 4. Соответственно и ко всем внутристоящим строкам тоже добавляем пробел, чтобы их было 4.

Вот ваш новый код, копируйте:

```
def summa(message):
    global amount
    try:
        amount = int(message.text.strip())
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Непонял')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summa)
        return 'Ошибка: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level'

    if amount > 0:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/EUR', callback_data='usd/eur')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('EUR/USD', callback_data='eur/usd')
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('USD/GBP', callback_data='usd/gbp')
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Другое', callback_data='else')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Валюта', reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи число больше нуля')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, summa)
```